# Rails - Nested Strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I'm trying to create an user register using two models User and profile, nested strong parameters in one controller. when I send parameter I get this error unknown attribute 'profiles_attributes' for User. and I can't create user neither profile :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :profile
 has_many :apartments
 has_many :session

 has_secure_password
 validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
 validates :password, presence: true

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end


class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :city
 has_many :profile_universities
 has_many :universities, through: :profile_universities
 has_many :profile_preferences
 has_many :preferences, through: :profile_preferences
 has_one :photo, :as => :imageable
end


class Api::V1::UserController < ApplicationController
  before_action :user_params 
  def create_without_facebook


    @user= User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        @profile = Profile.new(user_params[:profiles_attributes])

        render json:  [@user, @profile]
    else
        render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity

    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, profiles_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :gender, :marital_status, :ocupation, :budget, :question, :about, :city])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the singular `profile_attributes` if it's a `has_one`

Comment: I made this change, the user was created but the profile not. this is the response:  [{"id":55,"email":"safe77@jdisji.com","password_digest":"$2a$10$OZ1lvo7xXMVILl1uN3ArWePhUDuNOADR8Uve3ao9EY/f1MHu1vBQK","created_at":"2015-07-03T01:44:04.344Z","updated_at":"2015-07-03T01:44:04.344Z"},{"id":null,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"birthday":null,"gender":null,"marital_status":null,"ocupation":null,"budget":null,"question":null,"about":null,"user_id":null,"city_id":null,"profile_universities_id":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

Comment: code-formatting in comments is awful :(
If you tried something and it didn't work - can you rework the question? Or ask a new question (you can point to it from here if you want).

Comment: Note: you may need to update several places in your code, and possibly your form template too, to make this work - if they all used profiles_attributes...

Comment: @SaulFelipeRamirez Taryn's answer is correct. You should use profile_attributes in user_params method. Make sure that in your html form you have this change too. To debug this effectively use byebug and check output of user_params method in create action.